# CakePHP facebook integration logout issue with CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin

Tags: cakephp, facebook

I'm looking for a way with the [CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin) log users out of my app, but not log them out of their own facebook.

If I call my apps logout() function no matter what I do I just keep getting logged back in via facebook.  If I use the plugins facebook helper in the view to generate a logout button ($this->Facebook->logout()), it definetly logs the user out of my app...but it also logs them out of their own facebook which is kinda ridiculous.

So how do I work around this to log users out of my app, and but leave them logged into facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have them "logout" of your app (meaning the next time they try to use the app, they're going to be asked to authenticate your app again), then send an HTTP DELETE command to `me/permissions` using their user access token.

Comment: I'll give this a try, though I'm not sure if it's quite the behavior I'm looking for.  I'm looking for the behavior that most sites seem to manage with facebook integration.  That is when logging in with facebook for the first time you are prompted to allow the apps permissions.  You can logout at will from the app and at any time you can choose to log back in with facebook and it will not prompt again.  This is what I see on most sites, a quick example is imgur.com

Comment: Then use What Coder said in their answer. session_destroy will end the session on your website and not on facebook's web site.

Comment: Yeah I really wish that was the case (and it is with out this facebook plugin).  With the facebook plugin the user is instantly logged back in as soon as they refresh or navigate to another page

Comment: Then your third option is to also call FB.logout(), which logs them out of facebook too.  (Not very friendly in my opinion)

Comment: Yeah that's what we have now, and yeah it's not quite satisfactory.  So is the answer that this behavior is not standard that we're seeing and that CakePHP (and or CakePHP itself) is terrible, and there is no way to get it to work like every other site on the net already does without writing our own library?

Comment: I don't know CakePHP, but you might want to check all of their settings to see if there's something there to make it act like you want.  My preference is to HTTP DELETE when the user wants to log out.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I figured this one out just now, trying to figure this same thing out. Basically, although in the demos with webtechnick's examples, he puts "Facebook.Connect" in the AppController, but, if you want the selective logout piece, the Best place to put it is within the actual controllers that you want to use it in or put it in AppController and pass `noAuth=> true` into it. Either way, whichever way you choose, you set up one controller (facebook_controller.php?) to handle the logins, and set its component with the noauth set to false (which is default). That way, you have total control over whether or not the user is logged back into the site, and you can ACTUALLY log them out (with the regular `redirect($this->Auth->logout()`);

Let me give you an idea:

app_controller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Auth', 'Acl', 'Session');
       //or if you want access to "$this->Connect" universally:
       //   array('Auth', 'Facebook.Connect' => 
       //                      array('noauth'=>'true', 'Acl', 'Session');
}
```

users_controller.php:

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
var $helpers = array('Facebook.Facebook');
        //an example of the users controller, enabling connect, but
        // not authorizing the user (because logout() used by Auth is here)
    var $components = array('Email', 'Session', 'Facebook.Connect' => array('createUser'=>false, 'noauth'=>true));

        //login() doesnt need to be shown and can be left alone

        function logout(){
              if ($this->Connect->FB->getUser() == 0){
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }else{
                //ditch FB data for safety
                $this->Connect->FB->destroysession();
                //hope its all gone with this
        session_destroy();
                //logout and redirect to the screen that you usually do.
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }
        }
}
```

your "facebook_controller.php":
    class FacebookaController extends AppController {
    ...
    // i dont personally like to have his piece create my user so:
    var $components = array('Facebook.Connect' => array('createUser'=>false));
    ...

```
function login(){
//just need this stub function for later
$this->autoRender = false;
}

//you also need this for deauths or they will still be able to get into the site after deauth (against policy or whatever)
    function deauthorize(){
    //get user id from facebook API
    $uid = $this->Connect->FB->getUser();
    $record = $this->User->findByFacebookId($uid);
    $this->User->delete($record['id'], FALSE);  
    }
}
```

now your users/login.ctp file:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your app id', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/facebook/channel', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){
        if (response.status == "connected"){
            alert('redirecting you to auto facebook login');
                //here is out default place for login
            window.location.href = "http://"+window.location.hostname + "/facebook/login";
        }
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
<?php e($this->Facebook->login(array('registration-url'=>'http://www.yoursite.com/facebook/signup'))); ?>
```

And that should be pretty much it. I hope this helps someone reading this who still needs the help.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at $this->Facebook->disconnect();

It does exactly what you want.

http://projects.webtechnick.com/docs/facebook/default/FacebookHelper.html#disconnect

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried killing the [PHP session?](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions_3.htm)

```
 // this would destroy the session variables 
 session_destroy();
```