# How to implement logout with facebook connect in cakephp while preserving facebook login?

Tags: facebook, cakephp

how do you logout the user from your site in facebook api, while still keeping the user logged into facebook with cakephp? (I found the answer so wanted to share with everyone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this one out just now, after reading [CakePHP facebook integration logout issue with CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9137728/1133577).

Basically, although in the demos with webtechnick's examples, he puts the "Facebook.Connect" component in the AppController, if you want the selective logout piece, the Best place to put it is in reality within the actual controllers that you want to use it in. That or leave it in AppController and pass `noAuth=> true` into the Facebook.Connect component.

Either way, whichever way you choose, you set up one controller (facebook_controller.php?) to handle the facebook logins, and set its component with the noauth set to false (which is default, meaning DO authenticate [read connect.php to understand this]). That way, you have total control over when the users are logged into the site, and you can ACTUALLY log them out (with the regular `redirect($this->Auth->logout()`) without having the connect component immediately log them back in on redirect. Here is an implementation below:

Let me give you an idea:

app_controller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Auth', 'Acl', 'Session');
       //or if you want access to "$this->Connect" universally:
       //   array('Auth', 'Facebook.Connect' => 
       //                      array('noauth'=>'true'), 'Acl', 'Session');
}
```

users_controller.php:

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
var $helpers = array('Facebook.Facebook');
        //an example of the users controller, enabling connect, but
        // not authorizing the user (because logout() used by Auth is here)
    var $components = array('Email', 'Session', 'Facebook.Connect' => array('createUser'=>false, 'noauth'=>true));

        //login() doesnt need to be shown and can be left alone for your traditional users

        function logout(){
              //if there is no fb user, do the logout normal
              if ($this->Connect->FB->getUser() == 0){
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }else{
                //ditch FB data for safety
                $this->Connect->FB->destroysession();
                //hope its all gone with this
        session_destroy();
                //logout and redirect to the screen that you usually do.
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }
        }
}
```

your "facebook_controller.php":
    class FacebookaController extends AppController {
    ...
    // i dont personally like to have his piece create my user so:
    var $components = array('Facebook.Connect' => array('createUser'=>false));
    ...

```
function login(){
//just need this stub function for later
$this->autoRender = false;
}

//you also need this for deauths or they will still be able to get into the site after deauth (against policy or whatever)
    function deauthorize(){
    //get user id from facebook API
    $uid = $this->Connect->FB->getUser();
    $record = $this->User->findByFacebookId($uid);
    $this->User->delete($record['id'], FALSE);  
    }
}
```

now your users/login.ctp file:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your app id', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/facebook/channel', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){
        if (response.status == "connected"){
            alert('redirecting you to auto facebook login');
                //here is out default place for login
            window.location.href = "http://"+window.location.hostname + "/facebook/login";
        }
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
<?php e($this->Facebook->login(array('registration-url'=>'http://www.yoursite.com/facebook/signup'))); ?>
```

And that should be pretty much it. I hope this helps someone reading this who still needs the help.