# How to get Response from Facebook PHP SDK after Succesful login

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am using CakePHP 2.4 and Facebook PHP SDK 3.2.3 to create login form, which has two options: local login and login with facebook. I have been referring to [How do I integrate Facebook SDK login with cakephp 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037971/how-do-i-integrate-facebook-sdk-login-with-cakephp-2-x) on how to create login actions and view for Facebook login.

Now I have working local login, and when I press to facebook login, I am redirected to Facebook and back again to my login action of plugin Users. However I get no response in `$_GET['code']` or `$this->request->query['code']`.

This is my login action:

```
    public function login() { 
        if ($this->Auth->user()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are already registered and logged in!'),          'flash_info');
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == Configure::read('webakis.touchscreen_host')) {
            $this->request->data['User']['username'] = $this->request->data['User']['name'] . ' ' . $this->request->data['User']['surname'];
        }

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $this->User->saveField('last_login', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            if ($this->here == $this->Auth->loginRedirect) {
                $this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/';
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(sprintf(__('%s you have successfully logged in'), $this->Auth->user('name')), 'flash_success');
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
                $data = $this->request->data[$this->modelClass];
                $this->_setCookie(array('name' => 'AKIS'), 'User');
            }

            if (empty($data['return_to'])) {
                $data['return_to'] = null;
            }

            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect($data['return_to']));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid e-mail / password combination.  Please try again'), 'flash_error');
        }
    }
    // When facebook login is used, facebook always returns $_GET['code'].
    if($this->request->query('code')){ //Execution doesn't get in here

        Debugger::log($this->request->query);

        // User login successful
        $fb_user = $this->Facebook->getUser();          # Returns facebook user_id
        if ($fb_user){

            Debugger::log($fb_user);
            $fb_user = $this->Facebook->api('/me');     # Returns user information

            // We will varify if a local user exists first
            $local_user = $this->User->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array('email' => $fb_user['email'])
            ));

            // If exists, we will log them in
            if ($local_user){
                $this->Auth->login($local_user['User']);            # Manual Login
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } 

            // Otherwise we ll add a new user (Registration)
            else {
                $data['User'] = array(
                    'username'      => $fb_user['email'],                               # Normally Unique
                    'password'      => AuthComponent::password(uniqid(md5(mt_rand()))), # Set random password
                    'role'          => 'registered'
                );

                // You should change this part to include data validation
                $this->User->save($data, array('validate' => false));

                $this->redirect('/');
                // After registration we will redirect them back here so they will be logged in
                //$this->redirect(Router::url('/users/login?code=true', true));
            }
        }   
    }
    if (isset($this->request->params['named']['return_to'])) {
        $this->set('return_to', urldecode($this->request->params['named']['return_to']));
    } else {
        $this->set('return_to', false);
    }
    $allowRegistration = Configure::read('Users.allowRegistration');
    $this->set('allowRegistration', (is_null($allowRegistration) ? true : $allowRegistration));
    Configure::write('keyboard', 1);
}
```

Without getting response here, I can't handle my facebook login logic.

These are responses I get then facebook redirects me back to login page: 
[image]

Two interesting requests (with Url params and location shown):

```
GET oauth?....

client_id=671394586273323
ext=1406709978
hash=AeYXzQgAjCbRdY4g
redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/users/users/login
ret=login
sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3
state=9d030270aa50f2e52ac4aa66a37cd0fd

Location: http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/users/users/login?code=AQC_UtjKJU8a2leJMFAB4_1qx1mh1ww0-sRWdAD5vCocfKuZPTF4iSdKYwqxQUsm9N-_1tSPGfh3LYQXbXjYeY2onVBD6gTvJ5amvRZm5ZjI1OSYoLkqgjBsdfjWSdXTigCIQLf5d180keXTCf5jRiOXi8pWi0V2UxXqVl4K9QWWq2qGfSGuXlJMr32NZqKYR0Z93LyR1EiRFJPohfo6-j0kZJrNTkljCbY16Nrq1InqQLdYwGCOSg4IrbR0auaMIWTlnUCKFCr4DT3If_5HPFEDM6ZigeUvURM-q8y-CxDrRIctSmT4Bz1UevPqR-hOMbgKGzYUplatRywzjq_-R7bt&state=9d030270aa50f2e52ac4aa66a37cd0fd#_=_
```

GET login?code....

```
code=AQC_UtjKJU8a2leJMFAB4_1qx1mh1ww0-sRWdAD5vCocfKuZPTF4iSdKYwqxQUsm9N-_1tSPGfh3LYQXbXjYeY2onVBD6gTvJ5amvRZm5ZjI1OSYoLkqgjBsdfjWSdXTigCIQLf5d180keXTCf5jRiOXi8pWi0V2UxXqVl4K9QWWq2qGfSGuXlJMr32NZqKYR0Z93LyR1EiRFJPohfo6-j0kZJrNTkljCbY16Nrq1InqQLdYwGCOSg4IrbR0auaMIWTlnUCKFCr4DT3If_5HPFEDM6ZigeUvURM-q8y-CxDrRIctSmT4Bz1UevPqR-hOMbgKGzYUplatRywzjq_-R7bt
state=9d030270aa50f2e52ac4aa66a37cd0fd

Location:   http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/eng/login
```

I find it strange with code is not URL parameter in first request, but it is in URL, second response shows inverse situation.

OK, so this might be routing issue.

```
    $this->set('fb_login_url', $this->Facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => Router::url(array('plugin'=> 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), true))));
```

Router::url() returns: `http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/users/users/login`

My Router connects:

```
    Router::connect('/:language/login', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
    Router::connect('/:language/logout', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
    Router::connect('/:language/register', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
    Router::connect('/:language/users', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
    Router::connect('/:language/users/index/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
    Router::connect('/:language/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
    Router::connect('/:language/users/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

Al these urls redirects to: `http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/eng/login` . This might be problem, as Facebook SDK have different redirect URL, so then it redirects to `http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/users/users/login` , there is also request to redirect to `http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/eng/login`. The query parameter 'code' may get lost after this redirection.

Comment: It is advised that you don't create duplicate questions, and instead just edit your original one. In case it didn't received enough attention you can always gain reputation and offer a bounty... anyways, it's still not clear whether you have actually made sure that Facebook doesn't redirect with a `code` query parameter! Have you checked for example your browsers network console to see what exactly happens, maybe the parameter is being lost in an additional redirect on your server?

Comment: Sorry for duplicate, I really need to get it working at work. I logged `$this->request->query['code']` to my code, but it didn't print anything. And how do I check in firebug console if parameter is lost?

Comment: You are almost there, as you can see Facebook redirects with the `code` parameter, and the status returned from "your" server is a `302`, ie another redirect, so switch to the **Headers** tab and look for the `Location` response header, this will hold the redirect URL, which I assume doesn't contain the query parameters.

Comment: I updated article with two particular responses info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the network console and the from the headers that you've posted, your server is doing an additional redirect, and as already mentioned in my comment this is where the query parameters are being lost.

It looks like the redirect URL that you are passing to Facebook is wrong, it is

`http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/users/users/login`

which contains most likely at least a surplus `users` (not sure where this stems from, you'll have to figure that on your own) unless you are using a plugin called `Users` which contains a controller named `UsersController`, so maybe it should be more like

`http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/users/login`

However, considering that your server redirects to `/eng/login` when accessing `/users/users/login`, it may be that the redirect URL passed to Facebook is wrong altogether.

So first you'll have to figure out the actual proper URL of your login, and then make sure that `Router::url()` (assuming you are using the code from the linked question) actually generates that exact URL.

**Update**

From looking at your updated question, I don't see why any of these routes should cause a redirect, they aren't redirect routes, but just routes. The actual redirect will stem from somewhere else.

In case the redirect to `/eng/login` is acutally indended, then you'll have to make sure that you pass that URL as the redirect URL to Facebook, that is properly invoke `Router::url()` with the `language` key set so that it will match your first route

```
Router::url(
    array(
        'plugin' => 'users',
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login',
        'language' => 'eng'
    ),
    true
);
```

or use the `persist` option in your routes so that a call to `Router::url()` without the language key will match your route in case the current URL contains the language element, something along the lines of

```
Router::connect(
    '/:language/login',
    array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
    array('language' => '[a-z]{3}', 'persist' => array('language'))
);
// ...

// connect all default routes with a persistent language prefix
Router::connect(
    '/:language/:controller/',
    array('action' => 'index'),
    array('language' => '[a-z]{3}', 'persist' => array('language'))
);
Router::connect(
    '/:language/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    array('language' => '[a-z]{3}', 'persist' => array('language'))
);
```

or, as a last option, include the query string in the redirect to `/eng/login`

```
array(/* other route params */, '?' => $this->request->query)
```

Comment: `$this->set('fb_login_url', $this->Facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => Router::url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), true))));` I am using router this way, I'm going to try to add `'plugin' => 'users'` to it

Comment: The URL i get from Router::url is: `'http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/users/users/login'`. I think it can be incorrect, but I have it connected with my router as `Router::connect('/:language/users/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'), array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));`

Comment: I can type different urls to acess login page like `http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/eng/users/login` or `http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/eng/users/users/login` Due to my Router connects, but it always redirects to `http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/eng/login`

Comment: @kaktusas2598 So the redirect to `/eng/login` is not intended? It's pretty much impossible from there to give you any advice without seeing the whole picture, like the connected routes, your auth component configuration,  the actual location of your users controller, etc. All I can see from here is that the route you are showing may be missing the `persist` option for the language element.

Comment: Users Controller is in app/plugin/Users/Controller folder. I have appended info about Routes. I hope it can help a bit.

Comment: @kaktusas2598 I don't see why any of these routes should cause a redirect, they aren't redirect routes, but just routes. The actual redirect will stem from somewhere else. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, this worked, although at one point I got like 302 login requests then redirecting from facebook. Check my answer it may not be best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Router issues I changed redirect uri parameter in `$this->Facebook->getLoginUrl()` to `'redirect_uri' => Router::url('/', true).Configure::read('Config.language').'/login'` , as it resolves to `http://127.0.0.1.xip.io/eng/login` .

Now I get `$this->request->query('code')` param, so my code should work for now.