# Session issues in cakephp 2.x with facebook sdk in production

Tags: cakephp, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use Facebook PHP sdk with cakephp 2.x for login purpose.
And it is working with debug mode 1 or 2 but it is not working with debug mode 0.
It seems session is not working properly in production.
I search about it on the web many times but not get the right solution for me.

I read these two threads in detail but did not cope with the problem.
https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/issues/473
[How do I integrate Facebook SDK login with cakephp 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037971/how-do-i-integrate-facebook-sdk-login-with-cakephp-2-x)

I use these two functions in AppController for login.

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->disableCache();

    $this->Facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'app_id'                => 'appId',
        'app_secret'            => 'appSecret',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7',
    ));

    $this->Auth->allow(['.....']);
}

public function login()
{
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
    $this->loadModel("User");

    $user_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');

    $fb          = $this->Facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions

    $callback_url = HTTP_ROOT . 'login';
    $fb_login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl($callback_url, $permissions);

    $this->set('fb_login_url', $fb_login_url);

    if (!empty($user_id)) {
        //redirect to profile page if already logged in
        $this->redirect(... . );
    }

    //local login request
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        ......
    }

    // when facebook login is used
    elseif ($this->request->query('code')) {
        try {
            $accessToken = $fb->getAccessToken();

        } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            $this->Session->setFlash('Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(), 'error');
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            $this->Session->setFlash('Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(), 'error');
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }

        if (!isset($accessToken)) {
            if ($fb->getError()) {
                header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
                $this->Session->setFlash("Error: " . $fb->getError() . "\n", 'error');
                $this->Session->setFlash("Error Code: " . $fb->getErrorCode() . "\n", 'error');
                $this->Session->setFlash("Error Reason: " . $fb->getErrorReason() . "\n", 'error');
                $this->Session->setFlash("Error Description: " . $fb->getErrorDescription() . "\n", 'error');
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            } else {
                header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
                $this->Session->setFlash('Bad request', 'error');
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
        }

        // Logged in
        $oAuth2Client = $this->Facebook->getOAuth2Client();

        $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
        $tokenMetadata->validateAppId('1200125790051089'); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
        $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

        if (!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
            try {
                $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
            } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Error getting long-lived access token: ' . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n", 'error');
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
        }

        $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        $fb_access_token             = (string) $accessToken;

        if (isset($accessToken)) {
            try {
                // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
                $response = $this->Facebook->get('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email', $accessToken);
            } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(), 'error');
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(), 'error');
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }

            $fb_user = $response->getGraphUser();

            // We will varify if a local user exists first
            $local_user = $this->User->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array('facebook_id' => $fb_user['id']),
            ));

            // If exists, we will log them in
            if ($local_user) {
                $this->Auth->login($local_user['User']);
            } else {
                // we will create new user with facebook_id and log them in
                $data['User'] = array(.........);

                // You should change this part to include data validation
                $new_user = $this->User->save($data);
                $this->Auth->login($new_user['User']);
            }
            // redirect to profile page here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by session is not working properly? Also you don't need to start the session manually in your login, cake should handle it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some issues with the SDK and CakePHP 2.x as well. I wrote a small handler that lets the SDK make use of CakeSession.

You can find it here:

https://github.com/WrDX/FacebookCakeSessionPersistentDataHandler